# Настройка приоритета событий в html

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Например, у меня есть два квадратных элемента с одной общей стороной, и когда мышка переходит с одного на другой, от первого вызывается unmouseout(), а от второго - onmouseover(). Как настроить порядок вызова этих функций?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эти события срабатывают в этой последовательности, потому что сначала мышь покидает первый элемент и попадет на второй уже потом. Настроить это нельзя, но можно обойти. Например выполнять действия только по второму событию, при этом применять их еще и к первому элементу. Зависит от конкретной задачи.